Error Trying to Set CurrentCell in DataGridView Control
I have an unbound datagridview control on a Windows form with the SelectionMode set to Cell Select. Column index 13 contains the ID's of the assistants who worked on the current job, if applicable (i.e. some rows have Null in this column).
When there are one or more assistant ID's shown in this column, I add those ID's to a List(of Integer), look up each assistant's name and display those names in a messagebox. While the names are displayed, I want the datagridview to show the currently selected job name in column index 1.
This is all happening in the CellEnter event.
After (and while) the messagebox is displayed, I try to use the following code to set the focus to the job name column:
Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1)
Where the e.RowIndex is the currently selected row.
But I get the following error message:
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCellAddressCore function
Can someone please tell me how I can resolve this error?
Larry

You can't change the current cell in the CellEnter event handler because that would cause another CellEnter event to be raised before the current one has been handled. You may know that this would not lead to a stack overflow but the system does not, so it won't let it happen at all. You'll have to find some other appropriate time to change the cell. You might try CurrentCellChanged, but it might have the same problem. I'm not able to test at the moment.

Hi jm,I am not changing the current cell. I am simply reading the its values and storing them in a List(Of Integer). But I'm thinking that I need to move the focus away from that cell before I try to set the DataGridView1.CurrentCell.

You say that you're not changing the current cell but you showed code that literally sets the CurrentCell property, so what's that doing if not changing the current cell? Maybe you thought I meant changing the value in the cell that is current. I did not.
